# Reducing the number of nodes of a tree, to obtain nodes with more than one child node

Tags: r, tree

The following tree:

[image]

has been obtained from the following matrix

```
> mat
7  23 47 41 31
7  23 53 41 31
7  23 53 41 37
7  29 47 41 31
7  29 47 41 37
7  29 53 41 31
7  29 53 41 37
11 29 53 41 31
11 29 53 41 37
```

taking each columns of 'mat' as a level of the tree. If 'data' is the dataframe where the matrix 'mat' is stored

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
7  23 47 41 31
7  23 53 41 31
7  23 53 41 37
7  29 47 41 31
7  29 47 41 37
7  29 53 41 31
7  29 53 41 37
11 29 53 41 31
11 29 53 41 37
```

the code that produces above tree is the following

```
> data$pathString<-paste("0", data$V1,data$V2,data$V3,data$V4,data$V5,sep = "/")
> p_tree <- as.Node(data)
> export_graph(ToDiagrammeRGraph(p_tree), "tree.png")
```

I would like to modify the tree as follows: (1) if a node at level 'n', labelled by number x, has only one child node at level 'n+1', labelled by number y, then the program brings together these two nodes in one node labelled by the result of the product x*y; 2) if the node at level 'n+1' does not have child nodes, the program does nothing and starts again from another branch; 3) if the node at level 'n+1' has more than one child node, the program apply point (1) and starts again from each of child nodes.

For example, for the tree of our example, the code should:

- replace the nodes circled in red with a node labelled by 31*41*47=59737
- replace the nodes circled in orange with a node labelled by 53*41=2173
- replace the nodes circled in green with a node labelled by 47*41=1927
- replace the nodes circled in blue with a node labelled by 11*29*53*41=693187

[image]

Comment: How big is the a graph you are working on. Is it millions, thousands or hundreds of nodes? Is the graph static, where you can assume node data is stable over each tree pass? i.e. The data is stable over an algorthm pass.

Comment: @Technophobe01, the graph is static, and I have no more than 100 nodes

Comment: Can any node have more than 2 child?

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
  freq <- sapply(1:ncol(data), function(x) {
  df <- data[, 1:x, drop = FALSE]

  cc <- aggregate(df[, 1], as.list(df), FUN = length)
  merge(df, cc, by = colnames(df), sort = FALSE)[, "x"]
  })

data$pathString <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) {
  g <- 1
  for(i in 2:ncol(freq)) g <- c(g, 
        if(freq[x, i] == freq[x, i - 1]) g[i - 1] else g[i - 1] + 1)

  paste0(c("0", tapply(unlist(data[x, , drop = TRUE]), g, prod)), collapse = "/")
})


p_tree <- as.Node(data)

plot(p_tree)
```

[image]